Creating a Blazor App as a reusable application template in Visual Studio
My goal is to create a Blazor application with the 'Full Template' that is standardized to our business model. So that the look and feel of all the applications we create is in unison. This includes a CSS file, images, and a few classes built in. I want to learn how to make this template usable to our team, when they create a new Blazor App within Visual Studio.
I have been searching google for a few hours, this morning and can't seem to find what I am looking for. Perhaps I am not good at asking the question.
I don't expect anyone to do the work for me, or type out all the instructions. However, if anyone knows of a decent tutorial on this process, and can point me in the right direction.

Create a Blazor application that will be reused as a template for our business needs
Add the template to the list within Visual Studio, so that our team can simply create new Blazor App and select the custom template. Start coding

Any direction at all is appreciated. My searches seem to land on creating re-usable components. Which I understand. But what about when I want to create a full re-usable app template?

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/creating-custom-project-and-item-templates?view=vs-2022

You're probably not using the right search term.  Try "Visual Studio how to make a template".  You'll find the MS Doc provided by @Olaf and several other articles and YouTube tutorials.

Thank you for this.  After searching properly, I found some MS instructions and it was EASY BREEZY.  Thank you again!
